# Webscrape soccer odds, how would you approach this project?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

How would you as a skilled programmer approach a project on webscraping a site for all it's soccer odds?

I am trying to create a web scraper & crawler for a friend to analyze the odds from all www.cashpoint.com's soccer leagues.

As a new programmer, I now realize this task is bigger than I thought. The site contains javascript and there are more than just one site to scrape. 
I've become semi-familiar with python 3, web scraping and web crawling by following tutorials on youtube and made some small simple webscrapers. 
I'd like to ask a more skilled programmer how you would approach this project on making a program that scrapes all the soccer matches and then saves the info to a database.

I was thinking about web crawling through https://www.cashpoint.com and gather the links for the sites that contains the odds. I'd use bucky's spider to do this: https://github.com/buckyroberts/Spider.
After collecting the links I'd web scrape the pages using Selenium and xpath and store the info to a database. I've been looking at gingeleski's source code (https://github.com/gingeleski/odds-portal-scraper
) which does exactly this, just from another website. Basically you put links into a document and it'll scrape the odds and extract into a mysql database.
Another approach I thought about was to iterate through the leagues through seleniums webdriver:
***example to click the left menu bar.***

```
webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/site/index.html')
driver.find_element_by_id('left_menu_sports_id1008').click()
```

and then store this information to a database.

I'd love to hear and learn from a programmer how you would approach this project.

Thank you so much for reading this!

Regards from Christian

Comment: https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/site/index.html has a listing of the games and their odds, but it seems you are also trying to scrape information from pages accessible by clicking an element from the sidebar. If that is so, what pages are those?

Comment: Hey Ajax. Exactly! The pages are looking like the following. There's a lot. It's webcrawled with bucky's spider: https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/bets/xtra.html?group=461392&game=312004790, 
https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/bets/xtra.html?group=461392&game=312004791,
https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/bets/xtra.html?group=461392&game=312004792,
https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/bets/xtra.html?group=461392&game=312004793,
https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/bets/xtra.html?group=461392&game=312004794,
https://www.cashpoint.dk/en/bets/xtra.html?group=461392&game=312004795